# How to run PHP script without reloading the page?

Tags: php, ajax, random, refresh

Using a simple PHP script that randomly generates words based on words included in the PHP script. Would like to regenerate the random word combinations without having to reload the page. Any good ideas how to accomplish this?

Here's the site:
https://funnytee.me

Thanks!

Comment: Yea sure, I got a few

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX. There is lots of material out there on the web for you to start your reseach on

Comment: Thanks. Can you send me in the right direction please? Not sure what to look for.

Comment: Here's a good [starting point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: This does not relate to PHP per say, but to the way you call PHP from the client side.

Like RiggsFolly said you can use Javascript AJAX request for calling the PHP endpoint asynchronously without reloading the whole page reload.

Comment: Thank you both. I will read into it and try to learn how. Will post a succinct answer here if successful.